# Getting id or name of folder in fuelux tree

Tags: javascript, jquery, tree, fuelux

I'm trying to get the id or name of the selected folder in a fuelux tree but couldnt manage to get it done.

My tree is a classic folder/file type tree and I want to be able to see the id of the folder when I click on a file.

this is my datasource for tree

```
var treeDataSource = new DataSourceTree({
                data: [
                    { name: 'Elektronik Belgelerim', type: 'folder', 'icon-class': 'blue', additionalParameters: { id: 'F1' } },
                    { name: 'Gelen Kutusu', type: 'folder', 'icon-class': 'blue', additionalParameters: { id: 'F2' } },
                    { name: 'Giden Kutusu', type: 'folder', 'icon-class': 'blue', additionalParameters: { id: 'F3' } },
                    { name: 'Çöp Kutusu', type: 'folder','icon-class':'green', additionalParameters: { id: 'I1' } },
                    //{ name: 'Çöp Kutusu', type: 'item', 'icon-class': 'success', additionalParameters: { id: 'F4' } },

                    //{ name: 'Reports', type: 'item', additionalParameters: { id: 'I1' } },
                    //{ name: 'Finance', type: 'item', additionalParameters: { id: 'I2' } }
                ],
                delay: 400
            });
```

js function for tree begins like this inside tree-custom.js

```
var e = function (e, i) {
        this.$element = t(e), this.options = t.extend({}, t.fn.tree.defaults, i), this.$element.on("click", ".tree-item", t.proxy(function (t) {
            this.selectItem(t.currentTarget)
        }, this)), this.$element.on("click", ".tree-folder-header", t.proxy(function (t) {
            this.selectFolder(t.currentTarget)
        }, this)), this.render()
    };
```

and this is where I add the links under folders again inside trree-custom.js. Very primitive I know but that's all I can do with my current skillset. The part I added is between quotes. Rest came with beyondadmin theme and looks like usual fuelux.

```
selectFolder: function (e) {
            //alert("testselectFolder");
            //
            //alert($('#myTree').tree({ dataSource: dataSource }));

            var i, n, r, o = t(e),
                s = o.parent(),
                a = s.find(".tree-folder-content"),
                l = a.eq(0);
            //-----------------------------------------------
            var li = $('<li>');
            var TcgbLink = $('<a href=/E-Belge/Main/Folder/Inbox/?Type=1&DocumentTypeId=3>e-TCGB</div>' +"</br>");
            var FaturaLink = $('<a href=/E-Belge/Main/Folder/Inbox/?Type=1&DocumentTypeId=4>e-Fatura</div>' + "</br>");
            var Dolasim = $('<a href=>e-Dolasim Belgesi</div>');
            li.append(FaturaLink);
            a.append(li);
            li.append(TcgbLink);
            a.append(li);
            li.append(Dolasim);
            a.append(li);
            //-----------------------------------------------
            o.find(".fa.fa-folder").length ? (i = "opened", n = ".fa.fa-folder", r = "fa fa-folder-open", l.show(), a.children().length || this.populate(o)) : (i = "closed", n = ".fa.fa-folder-open", r = "fa fa-folder", l.hide(), this.options.cacheItems || l.empty()), s.find(n).eq(0).removeClass("fa fa-folder fa-folder-open").addClass(r), this.$element.trigger(i, o.data())

        },
```

Now these links are being generated under all 4 folders. I want to be able to get the id (or name, preferably Id) of the folder so I can assign new Type parameters to querystring.

So far I tried to reach the id with `this.data.id` to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of injecting the folder's children in the selectFolder callback, it is recommended to add the children via the dataSource callback (as in this example code: http://getfuelux.com/javascript.html#tree-usage-javascript).

The first argument to the dataSource is the "parent data" when you click on a tree node (with the second argument being the callback that you send the new array of child data).

This way you can use the [selected event](http://getfuelux.com/javascript.html#tree-usage-events) for getting your ID, because it gets the jQuery data passed to it.

Comment: Is there some you don't understand in the explanation above?

Comment: Actually your answer helped me a lot, made me think in a different way and I solved my issue with changing childnode names to href tags. Thanks :)